# How do you translate "Humanities Through The Arts" into Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

How do you translate "Humanities Through The Arts" into Latin? (It is the title of a textbook)

Answer (score 2):

How about *studia humaniora per artes*?

*studia humaniora* is the term from Renaissance humanist Latin from which "humanities" derives.